Behat Symfony Panther chrome failed
I m trying to test behat with panther in a container and I get this error:
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I add this options in behat.yaml file
                 capabilities:
                    extra_capabilities:
                        chromeOptions:
                            args:
                                - "headless"
                                - "no-sandbox"
                                - "disable-dev-shm-usage"


Some idee?
Thanks

Your question is missing for a lot of details. Also pather tests are not really supported in behat.
